# Duda sobre las constantes de animaciones en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Uso a esas constantes en un objeto Anímate para establecer la duración (corta, media o larga)

```
int final static config_shortAnimTime=200;
int final static config_mediumAnimTime=400;
int final static config_longAnimTime=500;
```

Hay alguna manera de obtener los valores establecidos por el usuario en el panel de configuración del dispositivo?

es decir si el usuario tiene establecido lentas o rápidas las animaciones, la aplicación lo tenga en cuenta.

Comment: Lo mejor en estos casos es no utilizar las constantes directamente, sino como valores por defecto. No sé cómo se obtienen esos resultados en Android (o lo que fuese) pero crearía un método similar a este: `public <T> T getConfig(String nombre, T defaultValue) { T config = /* lógica para buscar en donde podría estar almacenado */; if (config == null) config = getDefaultValue(nombre); return config; }` y el método `getDefaultValue` se encarga de devolver el valor de las constantes que tienes definidas como `static final <tipo>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El establecer la duración de la animación puede considerarse relativo ya que por ejemplo, si creas una animación de translación puedes tener que si estableces 1000 ms podría considerarse  un tiempo corto si la distancia es larga y viceversa. El tiempo para considerar si es corto o largo, depende de la animación que utilices.

Si se estableciera una constante para todas las animaciones, se perderia el control sobre las mismas.

Si te refieres a los tiempos definidos en las opciones de desarrollador no existe algun método expuesto para obtenerlos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera para obtener valores para las animaciones es usar los recursos de Android [android.R.integer.config...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.integer.html?hl=es)

```
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.status_bar_notification_info_maxnum);
```